# Is there an easy way to prove that this is the closed form of $\int x^ne^x\sin x$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, induction

I've been working on this problem for a while now.

**Problem**

I want to show that $$\int x^ne^x\sin (x) dx = A\left( \frac{1}{2} e^x\sin(x)\right)+B\left( \frac{1}{2} e^x\cos(x)\right)+C$$where $$A = \sum_{m=0}^n\left( \frac{-n![(-1-i)^{n-m+1}+(-1+i)^{n-m+1}]}{2^{n-m+1}m!}x^m\right)$$ and $$B = \sum_{m=0}^n\left( \frac{-n![(-1-i)^{n-m+3}+(-1+i)^{n-m+3}]}{2^{n-m+2}m!}x^m\right)$$ and $C$ is an arbitrary constant.

**Background**

I noticed that many integrals with an $x^n$ term (where $n$ is a nonnegative integer) can use integration by parts to eventually have the $x^n$ term vanish. I also noticed that $e^x$, $\sin (x)$ and $\cos (x)$ are cyclic in their derivatives. Naturally, this got me to ask the question: is there an easy way to (non-numerically) integrate $\int x^ne^x\sin (x) dx$?

I began with a few examples and noticed a few things. The important thing to notice is that the integrals seemed to be of the form $A\left( \frac{1}{2} e^x\sin(x)\right)+B\left( \frac{1}{2} e^x\cos(x)\right)+C$, where $A$ and $B$ are polynomials of degree $\leq n$. This made me excited, since the only method I am aware of to solve this integral is by using nested iterations of integration by parts, which is horrible for computing time, but finding a closed form for the coefficients in a polynomial might be much simpler. Basically, my intention is to find a closed form for this integral in terms of $n$.

**Things I have proven so far**

All of the following statements have already been proven, and might be useful.

*Lemma 1*: For any nonnegative integer $k$, $$\int x^{k+1}e^x\sin (x) dx = x\int x^ke^x\sin (x) dx - \int \left( \int x^ke^x\sin (x) dx \right) dx$$ Likewise, $$\int x^{k+1}e^x\cos (x) dx = x\int x^ke^x\cos (x) dx - \int \left( \int x^ke^x\cos (x) dx \right) dx$$

This just follows from a single use of integration by parts.

*Lemma 2*: $$\int x^ne^x\sin (x) dx = A\left( \frac{1}{2} e^x\sin(x)\right)+B\left( \frac{1}{2} e^x\cos(x)\right)+C \\\Leftrightarrow \int x^ne^x\cos (x) dx = -B\left( \frac{1}{2} e^x\sin(x)\right)+A\left( \frac{1}{2} e^x\cos(x)\right)+C$$

This lemma just shows that the integrals involving $\sin$ and $\cos$ are related. It is proven by setting $\cos (x) = \sin \left( x + \frac{\pi}{2} \right)$, etc. This is important because we only have to solve $\int x^ne^x\sin (x) dx$, as the $\cos$ integral will follow directly.

*Lemma 3*: $$\int x^ne^x\sin (x) dx = A\left( \frac{1}{2} e^x\sin(x)\right)+B\left( \frac{1}{2} e^x\cos(x)\right)+C$$ where $A$ and $B$ are polynomials of degree $\leq n$ and $C$ is an arbitrary integration constant.

This is shown by induction. Of course, what I'm trying to prove is what the coefficients in the polynomials actually *are*, not that the polynomials exist.

Lastly, I will mention that the discovery of the coefficients in $A$ and $B$ came from noticing sequences in the coefficients of the polynomials and representing them as compositions of simpler sequences. Of course, I have not proven that these are indeed the coefficients, and I could just be wrong about this, but it seems to work for the first thousand or so natural numbers $n$. After that, my computer doesn't like solving the integrals anymore, possibly because it too is using nested iterations of integration by parts (as stated in Lemma 1).

So far, to prove the proposition, I have tried using induction, but the problem seems to explode and become exponentially tedious to solve. Perhaps there's some simplification I'm overlooking? Some representation of the summand which makes the proof easier?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

\begin{align}\int x^ne^x\sin x\ dx =& \ \Im \int x^ne^{(1+i)x}\ dx 
=\Im \left( \frac{d^n}{da^n}\int e^{ax}\ dx \right)_{a=1+i} \\
=& \ \Im \left( \frac{d^n}{da^n}\frac{e^{ax}}a\right)_{a=1+i} 
=\Im \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k\binom nk k!\ x^{n-k} \frac{e^{ax}}{a^{k+1}}\bigg|_{a=1+i}\\
=&\ \Im \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{2^{(k+1)/2}} \frac{n!}{(n-k)!}
x^{n-k} e^{(1+i)x-i\frac{(k+1)\pi}4}\\
 =&\ \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k n!}{2^{(k+1)/2}(n-k)!} 
x^{n-k}e^x\sin \left(x-\frac{(k+1)\pi}4\right) \\
 =&\  \frac{A}{2} e^x\sin x+ \frac{B}{2} e^x\cos x
\end{align}
where
$$A = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k n!}{2^{(k-1)/2}(n-k)!} 
x^{n-k}\cos \frac{(k+1)\pi}4
$$
$$B = -\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k n!}{2^{(k-1)/2}(n-k)!}
x^{n-k}\sin \frac{(k+1)\pi}4
$$

Comment: Spectacular answer. Is there a way to remove the trig terms from the polynomial without using power series? Furthermore, is there a way to show that our expressions are equal?

Comment: @iateawalrus If you let $1\pm i= \sqrt2 e^{\pm i\frac\pi4}$ and $m =n-k$ in your $A$ and $B$, you may get the expressions obtained here. A term $ (n-m)!$ in the denominator may be missing.